# How to escape brackets in SPARQL string?

Tags: string, escaping, character, sparql, brackets

I'm trying to make a sparql query to: `http://sparql.lynx-project.eu/`
The graph: `http://sparql.lynx-project.eu/graph/eurovoc`
Which contains some entries with brackets in the prefLabel i.e. "sanction (EU)".

I'm trying to retrieve such exact match of such entries with:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?c ?label
WHERE {
GRAPH <http://sparql.lynx-project.eu/graph/eurovoc> {
?c a skos:Concept .
?c ?p ?label. 
FILTER regex(?label, "^sanction (EU)$", "i" )
FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
FILTER (?p IN (skos:prefLabel, skos:altLabel ) )
}  
}
```

It doesn't return anything. Also tried to escape the brackets with backslash but the query breaks. Do you know how to escape brackets in a sparql string?? thanks in advance!

Comment: `FILTER regex(str(?label), "^sanction \\(EU\\)$", "i" )`

Comment: It worked! I tried with single backlash, but didn't try double. Thanks a lot!!